# Stacking Critical Threat Range (TR) with Focus Attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Please note that PC is an [Aegis](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/aegis/) using Martial Maneuvers, Level 9 and has a BAB of +9/+4 and has the **Greater Unarmed Strike,** [Two Weapon Fighting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/two-weapon-fighting-combat-final/) feat and [Improved Critical](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-critical-combat-) feat among others

> **[Focused Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/rogue-genius-games/combat-feats/focused-attack-combat/) (Combat)**
>
> You can concentrate on a single attack to improve your chance of scoring a critical hit.
>
> Prerequisite: Base attack bonus +6.
>
> Benefit: When you take a full attack action, you can choose to make only one attack. This decision must be made before making your first attack. For every attack you could make but don’t, the critical threat range for the one attack you make increases by 1. This increase happens after all other adjustments to your critical threat range. Thus if you could make three melee attacks with a keen scimitar as a full attack, when you use Focused Attack you take a full attack action to make a single attack with a threat range of 13–20 (18–20 for a scimitar, 15–20 for a keen scimitar, 13–20 for giving up two attacks with Focused Attack and a keen scimitar).

and

> **[Broken Blade Stance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/broken-blade-maneuvers/#TOC-Broken-Blade-Stance)**
>
> The disciple of the Broken Blade has learned the flows of combat to a
>   degree and has the insight necessary to see the path to victory
>   through the patterns of steel his opponents weave before his eyes.
>   While in this stance, the initiator gains a competence bonus equal to
>   his initiator level to Acrobatics checks to avoid attacks of
>   opportunity, and **may make an additional attack when making a full
>   attack action. If the initiator is two weapon fighting, he gains this
>   extra attack for both hands. The attack(s) uses the initiator’s full
>   base attack bonus, plus any modifiers appropriate to the situation.**

1. Reading Broken Blade Stance, my Level 9 Aegis should have a full
   attack bonus of +9/+9/+9/+9/+4
2. Focus Attack says make one attack, any sacrificed attacks add +1 to
   critical threat range for the one attack. I my Aegis has a single
   attack of +9 and threatens on 16 out of 20.
3. How does Improved Critical factor in? Does the "doubling" of a
   weapon's critical threat range? Is it just double the weapon's
   critical threat range then factor in Focus Attack and the stance?

   EX: Greater Unarmed Attack 1d8 TR 20x2  = +9/+9/+9/+9/+4 to hit 1d8 damage TR19 with Focused Attack and Broken Blade Stance = +9 1d8 damage TR15x2
4. And, most important, is this legal and or broken?

Comment: When you say using martial maneuvers, is that the feat martial training or the alternative class features?

Comment: How is your level 9 aegis having an full attack bonus of +9/+9/+9/+9/+4? Since you are two weapon fighting to gain that many attacks, you must be taking at least a -2 on the attack rolls with a light weapon. Otherwise you would only have 3 attacks.

Comment: What weapon are you using? That would help us in answering for the specific BAB's and how things stack. Are you using a scimitar or unarmed strike?

Answer (score 2):

The feat [Focused Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/rogue-genius-games/combat-feats/focused-attack-combat/) says, "This increase happens after all other adjustments to your critical threat range." Thus the threat range adjustment from the feat Focused Attack occurs after the threat range adjustment from other sources like the feat [Improved Critical](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-critical-combat-).

For example, were the question's aegis—that's two-weapon fighting and that possesses the feats [Greater Unarmed Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/flaming-crab-games/combat-feats-3rd-party-flaming-crab-games/greater-unarmed-strike-combat/) and Improved Critical (unarmed strike)—armed with his unarmed strike and a dagger, he could take the full attack action, forgo 4 attacks, and make with his unarmed strike 1 attack that has a threat range of 15-20: from 20 to 19–20 *via* the feat Improved Critical (unarmed strike) then forgoing 4 attacks to increase the unarmed strike's threat range by 4 more than that to 15–20.

(Note that even if a weapon has a threat range of 1–20, typically an attack must still meet or exceed the target's AC to threaten the [critical hit](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Critical-Hits) unless the attack roll is a natural 20 *then* the attack must be confirmed normally, needing to *again* meet or exceed the target's AC unless the critical roll is a natural 20. A large threat range alone does *not* guarantee striking and dealing damage.)

Whether the third-party feat Focused Attack and the third-party stance [broken blade stance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/broken-blade-maneuvers/#TOC-Broken-Blade-Stance) are legal in your home campaign is something to discuss with the GM. Exceptional cases notwithstanding—like when making an attack with a weapon that possesses a magic weapon special ability that only activates on a confirmed critical hit or when making a particularly devastating magical touch attack—, I'd rather make multiple attacks than just one scary one, but I have terrible luck, and maybe yours is better.

Comment: You should mention that they still need to confirm the critical hit, and you are only guaranteed a hit when its a natural 20. The expanded threat range does not give a free hit (I made that mistake myself), it must still meet the AC.

Comment: With enough enemies within range of the weapon, and using whirlwind attack, this could be extremely easy to risk a critical hit. Likely works best for a magus using spell combat to get touch spells that crit more often.

Comment: @Fering Yeah, but it's still only *one* critical hit, and, like you pointed out, the attacker gets no bonus on the attack roll. (And, afterward, in your example, is surrounded by foes!) It could end up wasting the full attack when it could've been — like in the example — *five* chances to hit. But I don't do stats, like, *at all*, so I don't know if 1 25% chance is better than 5 5% chances or whatever.

Comment: Sometimes its about making sure you hit, HARD. Having your spells crit sounds like a great way to hit hard to me. More so since usually they are expended on that first hit. Touch spells tend to have a much higher chance of hitting due to the low touch AC, but except for magus they only crit on a nat 20.

Comment: @Fering That's… actually an interesting point. I don't play a lot of gishes, so I'll happily cede to your experience and incorporate your wisdom.

Comment: what is/are gishes?

Comment: @Fering [Here you go.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/30829/8610)

Comment: Vorpal only has effect on natural 20s, not on any critical hit.