# Is it balanced to allow a Divine Soul Sorcerer to swap out Empowered Healing for Extra Attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, balance, sorcerer

The [Divine Soul sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#DivineSoul) (*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 50) gets the Empowered Healing feature at 6th level:

> Starting at 6th level, the divine energy coursing through you can empower healing spells. Whenever you or an ally within 5 feet of you rolls dice to determine the number of hit points a spell restores, you can spend 1 sorcery point to reroll any number of those dice once, provided you aren’t incapacitated. You can use this feature only once per turn.

However, the version of the Favored Soul sorcerer (the original name for the subclass) in the [Modifying Classes Unearthed Arcana](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/modifying-classes) got Extra Attack at 6th level instead:

> Beginning at 6th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

I know that bards with the [College of Swords](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/bard#CollegeofSwords) (XGtE, p. 15-16) or [College of Valor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/bard#CollegeofValor) (PHB, p. 55) and [Bladesinging wizards](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/wizard#Bladesinging) (SCAG, p. 141-142 also get Extra Attack at 6th level.

**Compared to a College of Swords/College of Valor bard or a Bladesinging wizard, is a 6th level Sorcerer with the Extra Attack feature balanced?**

Comment: It may be worth keeping in mind that the UA version of the subclass you're referencing was from a [2015 UA](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/modifying-classes) as an example of how to create a new subclass. A substantially different version appeared in a [February 2017 UA](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/sorcerer), and then a revised version appeared in a [May 2017 UA](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/revised-subclasses) (which was very close to the version that was officially published in Xanathar's in November 2017).

Comment: Is a constraint of your question that there shall be no multi-classing for this character?  Your comment under the answer indicates that you had not intended to do any sorcerer/warlock multi-classing. Adding that as a constraint/limitation would make the question clearer for this modification to the published class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Maybe. It's up to your DM.

[In a vacuum](https://www.google.com/search?q=assume+a+spherical+cow+in+a+vacuum), the two features don't appear too unbalanced to swap. But D&D isn't played in a vacuum.

Favored Soul (UA 2015), Swords/Valor Bard, and Bladesinger Wizard are ["gish"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/30829/what-is-the-etymology-of-the-term-gish) archetypes. They have bonus proficiencies and other features that synergize with Extra Attack for a melee combat build.

Divine Soul Sorcerer doesn't have that synergy; therefore, Extra Attack wouldn't be overpowered for a single-class Divine Soul. Indeed, I would ask how you expect to survive as a weapon-based combatant with no armor and d6 HP.

The situation changes drastically if you add a [Hexblade Sorlock](https://www.google.com/search?q=divine+soul+hexblade+sorlock) splash for proficiencies and Cha-based attack bonus. Extra Attack provides that build with increased reliability & damage output, and avoids having to take more Warlock levels for Thirsting Blade, whereas Empowered Healing is useful in a much narrower range of circumstances. I would be leery about allowing it, but then I'm opposed to Hexblade splashes in general, so YMMV.

Comment: I wasn't planning on making a Hexblade Sorlock. Maybe I should have asked, "Compared to a College of Swords/College of Valor bard or a Bladesinging wizard, is a 6th level Sorcerer with the Extra Attack feature balanced?".

Comment: @FooBar: See this meta: [Don't signal your edits in text](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text). Rather than leaving an out-of-date answer and then appending the relevant answer at the end, you should edit the answer as a whole to read as if it was always the best version of itself (or, in this case, the version of itself that answers the question in its current form given the asker's clarification).

Comment: @V2Blast done, thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @FooBar Would you have a problem with a College of Swords Bard multi-classing 2 levels of Hexblade? If so, it seems that you believe the Hexblade is the issue, not a Sorcerer with extra attack at 6th level. You are right though, multi-classing must be considered when discussing balance. Wotc claims all official material is balanced with multi-classing taken into account.  Is there any other multi-class options that you believe are unbalanced for such a build?

Comment: @Caldrun Hexblade provides stronger 1st level benefits than other patrons, and PHB Warlock was already a frequently splashed class. I call that unbalanced; YMMV.

Comment: @FooBar "Indeed, I would ask how you expect to survive as a weapon-based combatant with no armor and d6 HP." Mage armor+Dex based build=no problem.