# Does the caster of Steel Wind Strike trigger effects based on the position they attack from or to?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, attack

The spell [Steel Wind Strike](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/steel-wind-strike) (XGE, p. 166) says:

> You flourish the weapon used in the casting and then vanish to strike like the wind. Choose up to five creatures you can see within range. Make a melee spell attack against each target. On a hit, a target takes 6d10 force damage.

The range is 30ft, so that would make any creature in a 30 ft circle* around you a valid target, in theory.

But a bunch of scenarios I can think of, that hinge on whether the attacker is moving between strike to be next to the creatures or not, hopefully by listing them all I can shake out an understanding of what is happening.

Also for reference, I'm aware of the question asking [Do you get advantage on the Steel Wind Strike spell's attacks because you "vanish"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/176830) as well as [Do Steel Wind Strike's attacks have advantage or disadvantage against distant prone targets?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134984/) but I think some of these examples might require a different answer.

What if any are the side effects of these situations?

- Targeting a creature inside the area of an [Alarm Spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/alarm) (Basic Rules , pg. 211), without starting or ending up inside the area - set the alarm off or not?
- Targeting a creature 5 foot inside the range of a caster who knows [Temporal Shunt](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/temporal-shunt) (so that all squares around the target are in range but you are not.), even though you start and end outside of range - the Steel Wind Striker can be targeted or not?
- You have [Crusader's Mantle](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/crusaders-mantle) (Player's Handbook, pg. 230) and the aura would overlap with a non-hostile who readied to make an attack as a reaction, but only 'during' the attack not before or after - the readied attack gets the damage bonus  or not?
- Targeting a creature with [Fire Shield](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fire-shield) (Basic Rules, pg. 242) or [Shadow of Moil](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shadow-of-moil) (Xanathar's Guide to Everything, pg. 164) if it starts and ends 5ft or 10ft away- those spells can lash out with fire or shadow or not?
- Targeting a creature within 5ft of another creature with the [Sentinel](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/sentinel) feat. but not starting or ending in range of the Sentinel - the sentinel can make an attack as a reaction or not?

For the sake of clarity, I'm not talking about the situation where the caster of Steel Wind Strike *starts* or *ends* that spell in range of, or inside the area of the above effects/spells, but where their targets are inside some area or range.

These feel like they cover a lot of the fundamentals for what can react to the attack from a Steel Wind Strike. It also differentiates between the vanishment being visual (similar to invisibility) or physical (perhaps similar to being ethereal/spectral but less well defined).

Does this tell us anything about the position of the caster of Steel Wind Strike when they make each attack?

---

*: Or your metric's** equivalent
**: No, not the metric system, the [Distance Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics))

Comment: Highly related: [How does Steel Wind Strike interact with Heated Body special trait?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/181326/63061). I think that this question is a dupe of the linked ones.

Comment: Is there a reason the prone question doesn't answer this one? It asks "Mechanically, when I make my attacks with steel wind strike, am I considered to be within 5 feet of each target" which, at least to me, seems to be what you're asking here

Comment: @Exempt-Medic because that covers a game mechanic/rule (advantage) that only affects the caster, as far as I can tell. i.e. "am I within 5ft of the target, not have I entered an area/range" It feels like it might be highly related but not the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Range is only relevant [when](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingaSpell) the spell is cast

> The target of a spell must be within the spell's range.
>
> Once a spell is cast, its effects aren't limited by its range, unless the spell's description says otherwise.

If the target is within range when you cast the spell, it’s a valid target. It doesn’t matter if you or they subsequently move out of range.

### Notwithstanding …

There is nothing in the wording of Steel Wind Strike that suggests the caster moves **at all**. They make melee attacks but it doesn’t say they *move* to make those attacks. So they don’t.

Answer (score -1):

These cases are all affected by range. For all except the case of *Temporal Shunt,* the distance the *Steel Wind Strike* caster is away from the target matters highly.

- The *Alarm* spell would not trigger because no creature is entering the designated area (assuming the caster stays outside of the designated area when casting *Steel Wind Strike*). The spell only triggers if the caster enters the designated area for some reason.
- The spellcaster that cast *Steel Wind Strike* can be targeted by *Temporal Shunt* in practically all cases because the range of *Temporal Shunt* is 120 feet, much larger than that of *Steel Wind Strike.*
- The bonus damage of *Crusader's Mantle* would still function. If the creature makes an attack as a reaction, and hits with the weapon attack, *Crusader's Mantle* explicitly allows it to add the extra damage ("when it hits with a weapon attack"). Of course, if the *Steel Wind Strike* caster stays out of range of a melee attack reaction, then the creature wouldn't get to make one in the first place.
- Spells like *Fire Shield* do get triggered, as long as the caster is within 5 feet, because *Steel Wind Strike* explicitly makes a "melee spell attack" and *Fire Shield* triggers on a "melee attack" (which includes melee spell attacks, as per PHB 195).
- By the same logic, the Sentinel feat is also triggered, as long as the caster of *Steel Wind Strike* is within 5 feet.

For the most part, anything that triggers on a "melee attack" also triggers on the melee spell attack made by *Steel Wind Strike*. **However, if the caster stays as far as possible away, it can no longer be targeted by many of these, because most specify a relatively short range.** For example, it can no longer trigger *Fire Shield* and *Sentinel.*

Comment: "Spells like Fire Shield do get triggered": the description of the *Fire Shield* states "whenever a creature **within 5 feet of you** hits you with a melee attack, the shield erupts with flame." Answers to linked questions state that when casting SWS you are not within 5ft of the target.

Comment: @Eddymage I specified that *Fire Shield* is only triggered if the caster of *Steel Wind Strike* is within 5 feet. Of course, if the caster is smart and stays out of range, it can't trigger *Fire Shield*, as I said in the answer.

Comment: Maybe you should specify that the caster is within 5ft of a creature with FS when they cast SWS and moreover they target the creature with FS.

Comment: Agreed, @Patricus : The phrasing in your answer, does not explicitly state whether you would consider the caster to be "within 5 feet" while making the melee spell attacks, even if they started & ended their turn outside that distance, & never moved there during their turn... Some interpretations (cough^JC^cough) assert that the caster will "start teleporting around the battlefield" ... "blink into view as [they] make each attack and then teleport to [their] final destination". I see no support for it in the phrasing, but the claim's been made that the caster is near each creature it attacks.