# Which multiclass to choose for melee-damage-dealing mage when starting from Wizard 5 / Fighter 1

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic

RPG: DnD 3.5

Hi! I need advice on which classes to choose to multiclass in to make a super-high-damage-dealing melee character who also knows magic (currently, the char is Wizard 5/Fighter 1). I've been doing research on magic weilding classes in melee, but am still unsure about which to choose. Kind of torn between Eldrich Knight, Duskblade, and Spellsword.

My current character is a level 5 wizard with 1 fighter level. As a wizard, he is specializing in Transmutation (focusing on spells like Bull's Strength, Cat's grace, etc). The forbidden schools as a wizard are Necromancy (kind of sorry I chose that one as forbidden) and Abjuration.

I know that if I leave him as a Wizard, he'll be able to do more damage overall, but melee is too much fun, so I want to grow him to do damage in melee. I've read that Duskblade doesn't care about Wizard specialization, so I'd be able to use Duskblade's Necro spells. But with Eldrich Knight I could advance my spell casting levels and get cooler feats, it seems. I tried to google which one is better: eldrich knight or duskblade, but couldn't find comparison of the two.

So my question is: **if my goal is to make a high-damage-dealing melee fighter who uses magic, should I choose Duskblade or Eldrich Knight (or something else) to multi-class in if I'm already a 5th lvl Transmutation Wizard & Fighter 1?**

Current character stats:

Race: Elf

Wizard 5 (spec: Transmutation, forbidden: Necro & Abjur) /Fighter 1

- str:14
- dex:14
- con:10
- int:15
- wis:12
- cha:13

HP: 27 :(

Relevant spells: Burning Hands, Mage Armor, Magic Weapon, Shield Bearer, Cat's Grace (Lesser), Blur, Bull's Strength, Scintillating Sphere.

Feats: great fortitude, craft wonderous item, toughness, quicken spell, weapon focus: longsword.

Comment: Banning Necromancy isn't much of a loss, but Abjuration is one of the *best* schools - especially for a gish.

Comment: @Miniman between *false life* and all the buffs to gain some undead immunities, plus some excellent curses/debuffs as great ranged backup options, Necromancy is a great school for a gish. Gishes want to ban Evocation and Enchantment even more than typical wizards. Agreed that Abjuration is a great school and never, ever should be banned by a gish since Abjurant Champion is the best way to gish.

Comment: @KRyan I was going to answer this, but your answer [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/30825/how-to-optimize-a-gishy-fighter-mage-character?rq=1) covers everything I would've said.

Comment: Yes, in agreeance with above, Abjuration and Transmutation are too powerful of schools to ban, especially Abjuration.

Answer (score 7):

The resource you're looking for is: [The Gish Handbook](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?321715-The-Gish-Handbook). With your current build, additional levels of wizard are absolutely indicated, as finding spells to increase your melee combat abilities is far easier than taking levels of fighter.

The PrC you'd normally take at this level is Abjurant Champion, as per [here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showsinglepost.php?p=16674503&postcount=8), though you've made Abjuration as one of your forbidden schools (see if you can change that to evocation through some kind of retraining quest as per DMG2). You may also want to explore the [swiftblade](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=333.0), though at present you don't qualify for it.

In your *particular* situation, assuming that you can't be permanently polymorphed into a dwarf for the notable runesmith, the eldritch knight is certainly not a horrible choice, and far better than additional levels of fighter. Use Eldritch knight to burn time until you can qualify for swiftblade, and then play with that class.

Comment: Abjurant Champion is perfect for any wizard in my personal opinion. So much to gain with no loss = overpowered.

Answer (score 1):

A Duskblade is a base class, which means you'd start anew with a new casting progression and it's always bad to lose spellcasting class levels to something else, whether it is to lose Wizard levels for Duskblade levels or the opposite.

The reason behind this is that higher level spells are always better than getting a lot more low level spells. Wizards start getting good melee buff spells such as *polymorph* and later *polymorph any object* and *shapechange* from Wiz7. Effectively, you've already lost something by getting that Fighter level (unless you couldn't get the requirements for Eldritch Knight by getting the competence elsewhere e.g. from the Militia regional feat from Player's Guide to Faerun).

Optimization-wise, friends who played both tell me Duskblades are a very solid class, almost overpowered during the early levels, but lose in power later, so despite losing two spellcaster levels your actual build might be the best among the given ones. If possible, follow with Abjurant Champion for the full BAB.

Comment: I don't think I can do Abjurant Champion because as a specialized Wizard, Abjuration is one of my forbidden schools.

So are you suggesting to go with Eldritch Knight for multiclassing in the future levels of this char?

Comment: Ah, you have abjuration as one of your forbidden schools. That's unfortunate. If you want to wield a weapon while polymorphed, you want to reach at least 16 BAB by level 20 (supposing your campaign lasts that long) which means you either go for the feat that lets you cast spells from a domain, choose war domain and get Incantatrix 3 to persist Divine Power (you need 14 wisdom, but items can help you) or lose caster levels or lose attacks per round. Anyway, you're aiming at wizard (or equivalent) 17